# SSRS Report Generator

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I have a problem on how to output this one on ssrs. 
I want to output something like this:

```
item1
  item1.1
    item1.1.1
item2
  itme2.1
  item2.1.2
    item2.1.2.1
    item2.1.2.2
    item2.1.2.3
  item2.1.3
```

Can I accomplish something like this if I group my rows?

Hope someone can help me with this. 
Thank You.

EDITED:

This is the sample data:

```
MBTC-CCWS07242014-04
C0000211957SMITH, JOHN                                       00000000100000007242014NONVAT  Assistance to employee J. SMITH
VASSISTANCE      7972           1900207140     07222014000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000LFC LF012014PHP  MB104SA10 Assistance to the 1110016520UNRELEASED
ACIB-MBTC       CASH IN BANK - METROBANK                                                                            000000001000000000000000000000     
AAP             ACCOUNTS PAYABLE                                                                                    000000000000000000000001000000
C0000052658Dela Cruz, Juan                                   00000000043800007242014NONVAT  SSC Advance Payment _5/1-5/7/13_HARBCO
VSSC ADVANCE PAYM8105           1900206889     07122014000000000438000000000000000000000000000000000000000000438000LFC     2014PHP  MB104SA10 SSC Advance Payment _5/1-1110016520UNRELEASED
C0000206125TEST COMPANY 1                                    00000000030000007242014NONVAT  Assistance 
VASSISTANCE      7984           1900207102     07222014000000000300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000300000LFC LF012014PHP  MB104SA10 Assistance to the 1110016520UNRELEASED
C0000052659COMPANY ONE                                       00000000033300007242014NONVAT  SSC Advance Payment
VSSC ADVANCE PAYM7987           1900206890     07182014000000000333000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333000LFC     2014PHP  MB104SA10 SSC Advance Payment_5/18-1110016520UNRELEASED
C0000050487MBTC                                              00000000117647107242014NONVAT  Retainers Fee_July 2014_I.Salting
VRETAINERS FEE_JU7898           1900207099     07122014000000001176471000000000000000000000000176471000000001000000LFC LF012014PHP  MB104SA10 Retainers Fee_July 2014_I1110016520UNRELEASED
```

for as to sql query.. can i keep it? since it is confidential.

Comment: Yes, grouping can help with that. What does your data look like for that? Can you group by item category, then line, then type (even if you're not displaying those)? Or are you only given the item number and expected to know that item1.1.1 is a subset of item1?

Comment: yeah something like that.. i want to list all the sublist of each items in the report

Comment: Which one, though? It'll change how you do your grouping. Can you post your SQL and some sample data?

Comment: i have included my sample output. it is an accounting entry